# Accessing array values using array key from Twig

Tags: php, twig

Does anyone know how (of if it's even possible!) to do this in Twig? I can't see anything in the documentation as to whether it's possible.

The PHP array is structured as below:

```
$data['data']['a']['title'] = 'Title 1';
$data['data']['a']['title'] = 'Title 2';
$data['data']['b']['title'] = 'Title 3';
```

Twig template code below:

```
{% for letter in 'a'..'z' %}
    {{ letter }}
    <ul>
        {% for key, item1 in data %}
            {% for item2 in item1 %}

                <li>{{ item2[key].title }}</li>

            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}                
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

**Edit:** After further investigation, it appears the attribute (see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) function should do the job but I am unsure as to how to use it in these circumstances.

Many thanks

Comment: have you got an error message? I think you spelt `letter` wrong. It should be `{{ item.letter.title }}`.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed this. Unfortunately this does not actually work as it is not possible to do it like the example above, it is purely for demonstration purposes to show what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Have you just tried this:

```
attribute(item2, key).title
```