# Twig - using variable

Tags: twig

I want to achive this is twig:

```
{{ form_widget(form.orderItems.0.enabled) }}
{{ form_widget(form.orderItems.1.enabled) }}
{{ form_widget(form.orderItems.2.enabled) }}

....
```

but the number to be a variable.

I tried this:

```
{% set index = 0 %}
{{ form_widget(form.orderItems.index.enabled) }}

Error: Method "index" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist
```

and this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.orderItems.{{index}}.enabled) }}

Error: Expected name or number
```

and this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.orderItems.~index~.enabled) }}
Error: Expected name or number
```

It is possible to achieve this :(

Comment: Have you tried {{ form_widget(form.orderItems.[index].enabled) }} ? Just a theory.

Comment: Yes :( - Expected name or number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some digging suggests you use the 'attribute' function - see [Accessing array values using array key from Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058994/accessing-array-values-using-array-key-from-twig).

I suppose that would be something like

```
form_widget(attribute(form.orderItems, index).enabled)
```

Unfortunately I can't easily test that at the moment, but it should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I am solving the same problem now and getting "expected name or number error" when I want to access variable dynamically. 
I can not find simple answer, how to dynamically replace some part of variable in twig.
But It works without first dot as was first comment here.

```
{{ form[othervariable value].vars.label }}
```

and NOT

```
{{ form.[value].name }}
```