# Twig template - access array within array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig, templating

Just started playing around with twig templates and i've ran into an issue. I got an array i'm looping over and extracting data from, within this array i've got another array (images) that I need to access, problem is I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's the feed i've got

```
0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => int 1
      'url' => string 'http://localhost' (length=16)
      'image' => string '8cgbfenx2n1.png' (length=15)
      'type' => string 'image' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => int 17
      'images' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'xjv5y4asev2.png' (length=15)
          1 => string 'kwwss8f6r34.gif' (length=15)
          2 => string '68yfnckk3c5.png' (length=15)
      'text' => string 'text' (length=4)
      'type' => string 'article' (length=7)
```

I'm then looping over and accessing like so

```
{%- if feed is not empty -%}
    {% for feedItems in feed %}

      <!-- article -->
      {% if feedItems.type == 'article' %}
            <!-- image -->
            <div class="gridTile-article-image">
              {% for image in feedItems.images %}
                {{ image }} <br />
              {% endfor %}
            </div>

      {% endif %}


    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
```

This doesn't throw an error but also doesn't output anything, anyone got any ideas have to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: is it working without the inner loop?

Comment: No need to check for emptyness of `feed`. With `Twig`'s `for` loop, you can do `{% else %} No feed {% endfor %}`.

Comment: Yep works without the inner loop just fine so I can return whats within the array, i'm just having trouble accessing an array within that array. Ah thanks D4V1D!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to output an entire array instead of one of its indices. `feedItem.images` is an array, as seen here:

```
 1 => 
array (size=10)
  'id' => int 17
  'images' => // The value of our index...
    array (size=3) // ..is an array
      0 => string 'xjv5y4asev2.png' (length=15)
      1 => string 'kwwss8f6r34.gif' (length=15)
      2 => string '68yfnckk3c5.png' (length=15)
  'text' => string 'text' (length=4)
  'type' => string 'article' (length=7)
```

My guess is that you have to refer to an index of `images` in the innermost block. For that, as this answer suggests, use the **[attribute](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html)** function:
[Accessing array values using array key from Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058994/accessing-array-values-using-array-key-from-twig)

So your code would like like this:

```
{%- if feed is not empty -%}
{% for feedItems in feed %}

  <!-- article -->
  {% if feedItems.type == 'article' %}
        <!-- image -->
        <div class="gridTile-article-image">
          {% for image in feedItems.images %}
            {{ attribute(image, 0) }} <br /> // Assuming you want to print "xjv5y4asev2.png"
          {% endfor %}
        </div>

  {% endif %}


{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks Kaloyan, I tried this but it was throwing the error "Impossible to access an attribute ("0") on a string variable ("ws1c8e2y2n1.png")" I worked out my problem, see below, thanks for your help though!

Comment: Glad you sorted that out! Also, yes, when dealing with somebody else's API / feed (sounds like your situation), always do **all** the checks you can think of, no matter how stupid they may sound :)

Answer (score 2):

So I worked out what I was missing. The following (original) syntax I had worked fine but I made a very stupid human error.

```
<div class="gridTile-article-image">
  {% for image in feedItems.images %}
    {{image}}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The reason this was returning blank was because the images array in the feed that I was querying was actually empty! I was looking at an array that was already populated but this wasn't of the type 'article' and therefore my code within that block wasn't returning any images because there weren't any!

Thanks for all your help!