# Twig Markup - Pulling out Variables

Tags: arrays, twig

Im new to twig and having a hard time getting what I need out of an array.

Here is my output from

{{ dump(items) }}

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'content' => 
        array (size=4)
          '#type' => string 'processed_text' (length=14)
          '#text' => string '8AS09DF8a90sd80' (length=15)
          '#format' => string 'basic_html' (length=10)
          '#langcode' => string 'en' (length=2)
      'attributes' => 
        object(Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute)[2249]
          protected 'storage' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
```

So I have an object(i think) with nested info inside of it

- I am trying to pull out the '#text' of 8AS09DF8a90sd80 but cant get anything but the dump to work.

Ive tried:

```
{{ dump(items[0]) }}

{{ dump(items['content']) }}

{{ items.content }}

{{ items.['content']['text'] }}
```

and a bunch of other formats, nothing works!!

How do I structure this in twig?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing array values using array key from Twig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058994/accessing-array-values-using-array-key-from-twig)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
{{ items.0.content['#langcode'] }}
```

We need to use:

- `0` to select the first key of the `items` array

  - `content` to select the `content` node

    - `#langcode` to get the value with `#langcode` key

Where `.` and `[]` have the same role: they are used to access to an attribute of an object, in this case the value associated to a key in an array. But writing `items.0.content.#langcode` would trigger a syntax error because `#` is not a valid character <sup>(1)</sup>, so we have to use the other syntax `['#langcode']`.

Source: [Official documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators).

<sup>(1)</sup>: I didn't tested but I'm pretty sure of this.

Comment: @Jason Did this answer helped you?