# Twig interprets variables as string and does not read their content

Tags: arrays, twig

I have an array in twig named  mark which contains classes. Here is an extract:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
     object(stdClass)#526 (11) {
        ["Algebre"]=>
        string(2) "11"
        ["ElectroCinetics"]=>
        string(2) "16"
        ["Statistics"]=>
        string(1) "8"
        ["French"]=>
        string(1) "9"
        ["Commerce_Int"]=>
        string(2) "14"
        ["Total"]=>
        string(5) "11.23"
        ["name"]=>
        string(16) "Jonh Doe"
    }
```

Now the point is I can't know the name of the keys because they are added dynamically by admin. All I can do is get them from database and store them into a variable called module.  SO i have something like this:

```
{%set module="Electrocinetics" %}
```

And so  when I want to display the mark I just do:
`Mark:{{mark.module}}`

and nothing is displayed because twig thinks the key it should seek for in the array is named module. But I want it to read the  content of the variable rather. Is there  a way to force twig to read the content of the variable instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `attribute` function.
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/attribute.html

Like this:

```
{%set module="Electrocinetics" %}

Mark:{{attribute(mark, module)}}
```

Playground example:
https://twigfiddle.com/1digwh

Related post:
[Accessing array values using array key from Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058994/accessing-array-values-using-array-key-from-twig)

Comment: Yeah works very well thank you

Comment: @Bandoss, I'm glad I could help. Please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: alright no problem